# bind command to nested listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I'm trying to bind a Command to a nested ListBox inside an itemsControl but somehow I can't find the right DataContext to execute the command.

XAML

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding VM1, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
  <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding SceneList}"

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PartialScenes}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedPartialScene}" >
         <ListBox.InputBindings>
              <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedPartialCommand}"/>
         </ListBox.InputBindings>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock>
                                  <Run Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListBox>
  </ItemsControl
</UserControl
```

VM

```
public class VM1
{
    public()
    {
          DeleteSelectedPartialCommand= new RelayCommand(Delete); 
    }

    public RelayCommand DeleteSelectedPartialCommand{ get; private set; }
    private void Delete()
    {
        Collection.Remove(SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

I've tried

```
 Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteSelectedPartialCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />

 and

 Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteSelectedPartialCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
```

Both options are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the root `DataContext` which is in `UserControl`.

Add a name to your `UserControl`

```
x:Name="MyUserControl"
```

And then for your command:

```
Command"{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=DataContext.DeleteSelectedPartialCommand}"
```